# Executing a select query from table in a database which has a dot in it

Tags: android, sqlite

So I have a table called `name_value` in a database called `cache.db`. The database name has a dot in it. When I try to execute the select query in database, I get an error as follows

```
android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: no such table: cache\.db.name_value (code 1 SQLITE_ERROR): , while compiling: SELECT name, value FROM `cache\.db.name_value`
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:6720)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1300(ActivityThread.java:237)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1913)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:223)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7660)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:592)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:947)
     Caused by: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: no such table: cache\.db.name_value (code 1 SQLITE_ERROR): , while compiling: SELECT name, value FROM `cache\.db.name_value`
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.nativePrepareStatement(Native Method)
```

My code

**Database Helper**

```
class DatabaseHelper(context: Context): SQLiteOpenHelper(context, CACHE_DB_NAME, null, CACHE_DB_VERSION) {

    companion object {
        const val CACHE_DB_NAME = "cache.db"
        const val CACHE_DB_VERSION =  8
    }

    override fun onCreate(db: SQLiteDatabase?) {
        // Already created.
    }

    override fun onUpgrade(db: SQLiteDatabase?, oldVersion: Int, newVersion: Int) {
        // No need for an upgrade
    }
}
```

**My code**

```
    val databaseHelper = DatabaseHelper(context).  // Context is passed a method parameter
    val db: SQLiteDatabase = databaseHelper.readableDatabase
    val nameValueList: MutableList<Array<Any>> = mutableListOf()
    with(db) {
        var cursor: Cursor? = null
        try {
            cursor = rawQuery("SELECT name, value FROM `item_cache\.db.name_value`", null)
            if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
                do {
                   nameValueList.add(arrayOf(cursor.getString(0), cursor.getString(1)))
                } while (cursor.moveToNext())
            }
        } finally {
            cursor?.close()
        }
    }
```

How do I get the code to execute without any errors?

Comment: In SQL, you escape table and column names with special characters by putting the name in double quotes - `"cache.db"`.

Comment: @Shawn so the query should be "SELECT name, value FROM \"item_cache.db\".name_value`" ?